# Процесс разработки на PHP

Tags: php, ide

Добрый день, на данный момент разрабатываю так:

1. Скачиваю с фтп (файлзила, правка)
2. Редактирую
3. Загружаю обратно

Как разрабатывать правильно?

Скачивать весь сайт для каждого рабочего места - неудобно, т.к. картинки весят 20гб.

Подскажите, как разрабатываете вы и посоветуйте что-нибдуь мне, пожалуйста. =)

Comment: http://cloud.github.com/downloads/GArik/progit/progit.ru.pdf

Comment: У меня стоит Apache + TortoiseSVN + Notepad++.

Т.е. есть локальная копия сайта, тестирую все у себя, IDE не пользуюсь (на работе так и не уговорили меня на что-нить)).

Кстати, Notepad++ имеет возможность работать с файлами по FTP - при сохранении он перезаливает их на сервер, надо только плагин поставить.

Answer (score 3):

А зачем качать картинки, качайте к себе только код. Редактируйте его, заливайте например в гит, а оттуда деплойте на прод сервер.

Comment: По сути, если я один работаю - смысла нет, что я поправил и в гит загрузил, что через фтп на прод сервер?

Comment: @Costa, не лукавьте, смысл есть, или вы хотите сказать, что у вас никогда не было необходимости откатить код, скажем, на версию месячной давности? С git'ом это довольно просто, а вот с тем способом, который используете вы - крайне проблематично (если точнее - нереально).

К тому-же, использование системы контроля версий, облегчает бубнопляски для тестирования нового или сомнительного функционала, еще это значительно облегчит вам жизнь если, все-таки, когда-то, вы будете работать с кодом не одни.

Да и, если вы не работали с git'ом, то вам все-равно придется с ним разобраться, поверьте :)

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Comment: @Costa, нет проблем, ссылка, которой я поделился в комментарии к вашему вопросу, лучшее место для старта.

Comment: Прочту к завтрашнему вечеру, наверняка появятся вопросы, можно будет у тебя минут 10 украсть? =)

Comment: @Costa, только если гугл на них не может нормально ответить, что, к слову, мало вероятно.

Еще, если нет проблем с английским, можно посмотреть
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDR433b0HJY

Answer (score 0):

Обычно держу локальную копию проекта, над которым работаю. Либо на сервере, помимо Production, живёт на поддомене Development версия проекта только для разработки и тестов (иногда их несколько).

Когда картинок 20Гб, обычно они живут на отдельном поддомене где-нибудь на [S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/).

IDE, которой пользуюсь, [Coda](http://panic.com/coda/), весьма удобно работает с парой локальный-удалённый сервер: можно и редактировать локально, синхронизируя с ремоутным сервером после проверок; и позволяет редактировать прямо на удалённом серве файл через (S)FTP, как будто он локальный. В прочих случаях деплоймент идёт через [git](http://git-scm.com/).

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий! Можно еще вопрос по Коде, если код начинается не с <?php , а с <? очень глючит подсветка, определяет много кода как комментарии и подсвечивает серым, может сталкивались?

Comment: Это во 2-й версии? У меня до сих пор 1-я и за ней не замечал такого. Лучше, может, писать по стандарту, `<?php` и `<?php echo`, чтобы не возникало [всех этих мелких проблем](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use), плюс подсветку синтаксиса, и выключенную опцию `short_opentag` на рабочем хостинге, где её нельзя поменять (вдруг).

Answer (score 0):

[Cloud9 IDE](https://c9.io/) - Можно подключаться напрямую к фтп и онлайн править код.

Answer (score 0):

Я рекомендую [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/), эта IDE имеет почти безграничные возможности при быстрой работе. Умеет подключатся к FTP и автоматически аплодить изменения на сервер.

Comment: Как раз сейчас пробую, есть одна проблема, если работаю с отдельным файлом, а не проектом, и в файле используется функция, объявленная в другом файле, то при повторном ее вводе не работает автокомплит, не подскажите, как это решить?

Comment: Другой файл на сервере, phpstorm о нем ничего не знает.

Comment: Ну скорее всего PhpStorm о нем и не узнает...